# How can I use different syntax to reduce lines in the code below?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I would like to reduce the number of lines in the component < Counter > code and make it sleeker?
Is there a different syntax to render() that I can use to shorten the code?

```
import Counter from "./Counter";

export default class Bookstore extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <TopBar>React Components are state machines</TopBar>
        <h1 className="headline white-text">* ^ * Stateful Bookstore * ^ *</h1>
        <Counter count={this.count} name="Employees" />
        <Counter count={this.count} name="Customers" />
        <br />
        <hr />
        <NameInput />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  add_count = event => {
    console.log(event.target);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hbox space-between mt20">
        <h3 className="paragraph">
          {this.props.name}: {this.state.count}
        </h3>
        <button className="button" onClick={this.add_count.bind(this)}>
          {this.props.name}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is working code, and you just want tips on cleaning it up/making it more concise, please head on over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use functional component instead. Also as Mike said it’s better to use codereview

Answer (score 4):

Use a function component instead of a `React.Component`

```js
const Counter = ({ name }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  return (
    <div className="hbox space-between mt20">
      <h3 className="paragraph">
        {name}: {count}
      </h3>
      <button className="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        {name}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it sleeker you also can define a custom hook in a separate file and import it.

```
//Custom Counter Hook
function useCounter( start = 0 ) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(start);
  function increment() {
    setCount(count => count + step);
  }
  return [count, increment];
}
```

then import the hook here:

```
const Counter = ({ name }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useCounter(0); 
  return (
    <div className="hbox space-between mt20">
      <h3 className="paragraph">
        {name}: {counter}
      </h3>

      <button className="button" onClick={setCounter}>
        {name}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```